# How to get Google Cloud Platform extension for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, google-cloud-visualstudio

I am unable to get the Google cloud platform extension in my Visual Studio 2013 though Online Extensions and Updates in my Visual Studio IDE. I am using **Windows 7 OS( 32 -bit)**. Is there any other way to get my ASP.NET application to work with Google Compute Engine ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to install *Cloud Tools for Visual Studio* on VS 2013. The lowest supported version of the extension is 2015. You could log a feature request on the project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/google-cloud-visualstudio) though.

Is there a particular reason you want to stick with 2013?